# append or join value from one dataframe to every row in another dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, append

I'm normally OK on the joining and appending front, but this one has got me stumped.

I've got one dataframe with only one row in it.  I have another with multiple rows.  I want to append the value from one of the columns of my first dataframe to every row of my second.

df1:

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word |

df2:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

Output I'm seeking:

df2

| id | data | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | word |
| 2 | b | word |
| 3 | c | word |

I figured that this was along the right lines, but it listed out NaN for all rows:

```
df2 = df2.append(df1[df1['Value'] == 1])
```

I guess I could just join on the id value and then copy the value to all rows, but I assumed there was a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the first element in the value column of df1 and assign it to value column of df2

```
df2['value'] = df1.loc[0, 'value']
```